# migrating to spring boot 2.7.13 where to set web-inf persistence-unit-ref as we are Obtaining an EntityManagerFactory from JNDI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jndi

Thanks in advance, migrating from spring 4 to spring boot 2.7.13 getting below exception, i am not sure how to move  persistence-unit-ref from web.xml to ServletInitializer onLoad, thinking that could be the cause.

```
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/compDs</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
            value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

### web application context xml

<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/compPersistenceUnit"/>

### web.xml

```
<persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/compPersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>compPersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-unit-ref>
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: DefaultCell/nodes/DefaultNode/servers/server1, name: persistence/compPersistenceUnit: First component in name persistence/compPersistenceUnit not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$453/0x00000000d30d5440.getObject(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
... 139 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: DefaultCell/nodes/DefaultNode/servers/server1, name: persistence/compPersistenceUnit: First component in name persistence/compPersistenceUnit not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4565)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1823)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1778)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1435)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:617)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:149)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:157)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$$Lambda$506/0x00000000d34115a0.doInContext(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:92)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:157)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:105)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:114)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:239)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
... 156 more
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2534)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1277)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4677)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4672)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:871)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.getTargetContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4671)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:5283)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2208)
at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2959)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2955)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:871)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2953)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1819)
... 174 more

Extpecting 'entityManagerFactory' to be created as if it was working with spring 4.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.